# PVOP_VCALL2 linux function

Tags: linux, function, linux-kernel

I was going through Linux kernel code, wherein I found `PVOP_VCALL2` functions. I would like to know what does this function do? And how is it defined and where?

I found the call in  `arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h` file. The one which i was trying to find was `PVOP_VCALL2(pv_lock_ops.spin_lock_flags, lock, flags)`.

Answer (score 0):

PVOP_VCALL2 is a macro for hypercall, with 2 params